# Is there a way to set/bind to component variables in html part

Tags: angular

I am new to ng world and I would like to figure out how to set/bind value of variables declared in component.ts at any point in html to some html context?

here is an example:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required>

    <p>Value: {{ name }}</p>
    <p>Valid: {{ myIsValid }}</p>

    <div [myIsValid] = ctrl.valid  ???? is this possible?
})

export class SimpleNgModelComp {
  name: string = '';
  myIsValid:boolean = true;
}
```

link to source code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bf3xs4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: can you elaborate little more, what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi, sure, take a look at this part:  <div [myIsValid] = ctrl.valid  ???? is this possible?

I was hoping to bind ctrl.valid value to a variable from component class called myIsValid

is there such a way to do so in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@ViewChild` in your component class like:

```
@ViewChild('ctrl') myIsValid;
```

And use `myIsValid` anywhere you want.

Comment: Hi, YogendraR, this is an solution however not that I am looking for. As I stated in my question I want to set value in HTML, not in component class. Component Class shall stay untouched

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it like this :

```
  <input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" (keyup)="myIsValid=name" required>

<p>Value={{name}}</p>
<p>Valid={{myIsValid}}</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer you can create keyup  event on name input,  it will update as soon as the name is update, hope this will help you

Comment: thanks, however that is also slightly different solution than I am looking for. I was hoping I could set the binding on an html element and it lasts until view destroys. I am not looking for events